# Python - Read and assign data from a .csv to pre-defined variables

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read data from a CSV file (A), extract data, and write that to a different CSV file (B). In the new file B, I want to have two rows. The first row should contain all the predefined variables and row 2 should be filled with all the values that belong to the specific variable in row 1.

I hope anyone can tell me the best way to achieve this. (i added the .csv file i used at the end of this post)

**(A) Python code**

```
import re
import csv

#Call for the export file
data = open('C:/Exports/Export 3.csv')

#Make a list with the predefined variables
definition = ["record_id", "abbreviation", "study_id", "step_count",
"distance", "ambulation_time", "velocity", "cadence", "norm_velocity",
"step_time_differential", "step_length_differential",
"cycle_time_differential", "step_time", "step_length", "step_extremity",
"cycle_time", "stride_length", "hh_base_support", "swing_time",
"stance_time", "single_support_time", "double_support_time", "toe_in_out"]

my_data = {}

#Show data for each row without whitespace
for line in data:
    line = line.rstrip()
    #print(line)
    values = re.findall("-?[0-9].+", line)
    print(values)
```

**This is a part of the output the above code will generate:**

```
[]
['3;']
['292,34;']
['1,67;']
['175,1;']
['107,8;']
[]
['0,004;']
['1,051;']
['0,008;']
[]
[]
['0,558;0,554']
['96,746;97,797']
[]
['1,116;1,108']
['192,159;197,122']
['2,988;6,32']
['0,466;0,466']
['0,65;0,642']
['0,466;0,466']
['0,184;0,176']
['41,8;42,1']
['58,2;57,9']
['41,8;42,1']
['16,5;15,9']
['-1,1;4']
```

As you can see in the output code, there are some lines that contain two values like: ['2,988;6,32'] these need to become 1 value, by calculating the average over the two values before writing them to a csv file.

**(B) Desired output**

```
record_id  abbreviation  study_id  step_count  distance 
1                                  3           292,34
```

If you like, you can play with the export file you can download it here:
[CSV export file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03062446993293567917)

Comment: Give more info relating to sample input and sample output, so you don't get made up answers

Comment: Thanks! I changed some text to make it easier to understand and added the input .csv file i used at the end. Also added an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open your file with the `csv` library, `semi-colon` separated and then compare the first column with the items in your definition. This pretty much does that:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(str)

#Make a list with the predefined variables
definition = ["record_id", "abbreviation", "study_id", "step_count",
"distance", "ambulation_time", "velocity", "cadence", "norm_velocity",
"step_time_differential", "step_length_differential",
"cycle_time_differential", "step_time", "step_length", "step_extremity",
"cycle_time", "stride_length", "hh_base_support", "swing_time",
"stance_time", "single_support_time", "double_support_time", "toe_in_out"]

with open('C:/Exports/Export 3.csv', 'r') as f, 
     open('C:/Exports/result.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers

    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=definition, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        for item in definition:
            h = item.replace('_','')
            r0 = row[0].lower().replace(' ','')
            if h in r0:
                print(h, r0)
                data[item] = row[1] 

    data['record_id'] = 1 # record id does not exist in input file: Export 3.csv

    writer.writerow(data)
```

To get average from items, you can use:

```
try: 
   avg = (float(row[1].replace(',', '.')) + float(row[2].replace(',', '.')))/2 
except ValueError:
   avg = 0 # for cases with empty strings or commas
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! this is helping me bigtime!, i still have some small problems which i posted as an answer underneath.

Comment: Hi @Yak, you can fix the mismatch by making `definition` match more closely the names in the input file. As for the averaging, see my updates

Comment: Yea this is what i thought aswell Moses, but for example velocity matches velocity exactly, but in the result.csv the velocity value is empty. This seems to happen, because there are more variables with velocity in it's name like: stridevelocitystddev. 

As for the average, where exactly in the code should i put it, so it will also be passed on to the result.csv?

Comment: Hello @Moses Koledoye, do you have any idea on how to fix the last pieces of the puzzle? Would be rlly grateful if you dol!

Comment: could you please take a look at this post of mine? I tried to explain in detail what problems i am facing. [Read from & Write values to a .csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206262/python-3-read-from-write-values-to-a-csv)

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly perfect! seems like there are some small problems. 
In the result.csv i am missing the values of the following variables:

```
step_time
step_length
cycle_time  
stride_length   
hh_base_support 
swing_time  
stance_time 
single_supp_time    
double_supp_time    
toe_in_out
```

I used this part of the code to check the outcomes:

```
print(h, r0, row[1], row[2])
```

which gives me back the following info:

```
stepcount stepcount 3  
distance distance 292,34  
ambulationtime ambulationtime 1,67  
velocity velocity 175,1  
cadence cadence 107,8  
velocity normalizedvelocity ,  
normalizedvelocity normalizedvelocity ,  
steptimedifferential steptimedifferential 0,004  
steptime steptimedifferential 0,004  
steplengthdifferential steplengthdifferential 1,051  
steplength steplengthdifferential 1,051  
cycletimedifferential cycletimedifferential 0,008  
cycletime cycletimedifferential 0,008  
steptime steptime(sec) 0,558 0,554
steplength steplength(cm) 96,746 97,797
stepextremity stepextremity(ratio) , ,
cycletime cycletime(sec) 1,116 1,108
stridelength stridelength(cm) 192,159 197,122
hhbasesupport hhbasesupport(cm) 2,988 6,32
swingtime swingtime(sec) 0,466 0,466
stancetime stancetime(sec) 0,65 0,642
velocity stridevelocity 172,185 177,908
steptime steptimestddev , 0,006
stridelength stridelengthstddev , ,
swingtime swingtimestddev , ,
stancetime stancetimestddev , ,
velocity stridevelocitystddev , ,
singlesupptime singlesupptimestddev , ,
doublesupptime doublesupptimestddev , ,
```

From the above output, you can see there are some problems with names matching with multiple strings(like velocity) and some not matching at all(like toe_in_out) I have no clue how to fix this.

Also i tried to calculate the average whenever there are two values, but this gives me the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float. Which i think is caused cause of the comma's. I tried to apply the following code in the for loop to calculate the average:

```
float(row[1]+float(row[2])) / 2
```